# How to sort a list alphabetically in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

```
 List<ValueValid> lst = DataService
 .GetProductValidChildren(product.ProdType, (decimal)enumValue);
```

lst gives me a list of country names.. I need to sort this.. could any one of you help me??

Comment: Please tell me you are going to rename that variable to be countries and not lst...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the list is not parameterized, you can use:

```
lst.Sort();
```

**EDIT**: If it's a list of `ValueValid`, you can use:

```
lst.Sort(delegate(ValueValid v1, ValueValid v2) { return v1.Country.CompareTo(v2.Country); });
```

Assuming `ValueValid` has a property named `Country`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Sort methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) on the `List<T>` class!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a System.Collections.SortedList

Answer (score 0):

lst.OrderBy(w=>w.Country));